SQLite Database gets locked while creating index
I have a 8GB Sqlite database and I'm trying to create an index on one column of a table with 600K rows. Every time I attempt to create the index, I get the following error:

Runtime error: database is locked (5)

There are no other processes accessing the database. How can I solve this problem?

I was able to solve the problem by increasing the timeout.
